# - noobie question- What is a Hero Image?

Tags: usability

Reading the Nielsen Norman Group about the [Carousel usability](http://httphttps://www.nngroup.com/articles/designing-effective-carousels/) i found that term and really don't know what it means, somebody could help me to understand it please?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hero_image

Comment: Closing those because it shows no research effort.

Answer (score 1):

Fede -

In the context of this article, a 'hero' image is used to main 'your site's/page's main image'. Think of it like a homepage image, or a banner image.

Answer (score 1):

It's the large dominating image used usually on your site's home page.  You'll recognise them, they are everywhere at the moment.  Think big relevant usually darkened photo with writing in front of, or maybe cut out of it, right there on the home page.

More interesting is why is it called a hero image. It most likely comes from the term hero prop which are detailed props used for closeups in film making.